# Comparing values in Two variable using VBA Like operator

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I would like to compare values(string ) stored in two variable, just like we can compare a variable with a string using like operator

So basically i would like to use "like "operator and have two variable contents comparison or get simililar functionality .

Below is the snippet of the code . Please guide me

```
If ( nametwo Like " * " & monthname & " * "  ) OR ( nametwo Like " * " & yearname& " * " ) Then

'some action 

Endif
```

Note : nametwo , monthname  and yearname are string variables

Comment: what is the problem with the above.  It should work if you put a space between `yearname` and `&`

Comment: oh and remove the spaces around the `*` so only `"*"`

Comment: The if condition is not working when when  name2 = "May 2018"  , monthname = "May"  yearname ="2018"

Comment: see my comments for your typos.

Comment: also `name2` <> `nametwo`

Comment: Wow thanks it did work  u r awesome :) thanks a million

Comment: You might be looking for InStrRev https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instrrev-function and InStr https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function functions.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to the question was proper spacing

```
If (nametwo Like "*" & monthname & "*") And (nametwo Like "*" & yearname & "*") Then

csworksheetcount = ws.Index


End If
```

Comment: Please, reformat your answer to make it more readable. Use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).